# "Associated reputation" displayed for Code Review

Tags: discussion, reputation, beta-sites

I was wondering if it made sense to declare Stack Overflow a sort of "associated website" of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which would allow users of that site to inspect a contributor's profile state on SO. The reasoning is that CR has comparably little traffic and few contributors, and so the reputation gained on that site alone may not necessarily give users the full picture about the contributor's areas of expertise.

This situation is more or less unique to SO/CR, because both sites cater to essentially the same audience, but have distinct scopes of questions.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you're proposing. Can't I already go to the user's profile to see their SO information, if the accounts were associated? Or do you want to visualize this up front in their user card?

Comment: @Bart: Yes, visualising it on the user card may be what I had in mind... with a link to the SO profile perhaps.